# Graph Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I have this example graph

```
graph = { "v1" : ["v3"],
          "v2" : ["v3", "v5"],
          "v3" : ["v1", "v2", "v4", "v5"],
          "v4" : ["v3"],
          "v5" : ["v3", "v2"],
          "v6" : []
        }
```

And I have this two algorithm for generating edges and finding isolated nodes:

```
def edges(g):
    edges = []
    for node in g[node]:
        edges.append((node, g[node]))
    return edges

def isolated(g):
    result = []
    for node in g[node]:
        if not g[node]:
            result += node
    return result
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? The line `for node in g[node]:` seems very strange. This can be the problem! Try `for node in g:`.

Comment: How are you calling these functions? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: By isolated, you mean nodes with no edges into or out of?  What if you have two unconnected subgrapghs like A-B, C-D?  The  two are not connected to each other, but they have connections to other nodes.

Comment: Hi guys, by isolated I mean nodes with no edges, like "v6". And yes, I want to traverse g, by I want also to traverse g[node], How I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is this:

```
graph = { "v1" : ["v3"],
          "v2" : ["v3", "v5"],
          "v3" : ["v1", "v2", "v4", "v5"],
          "v4" : ["v3"],
          "v5" : ["v3", "v2"],
          "v6" : []
        }

res = [k for k, v in graph.items() if not v]

print(res)
```

you'll get `['v6']` because it is the only with no nodes assoc

Comment: please explain what is res and that list stuff? That computes isolated? What about my edges algorithm?

Comment: @YahatmaAmid there's no need for the edge algo, basically you go throw elements in your dict, and filter the one that have an empty list

Comment: This returns all nodes that do not have _outgoing_ edges, but they could very well have _incoming_ edges.

Comment: @tobias_k is an undirected graph. Thank you Damian for your help, very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to list the edges in the form of a list of tuples containing a node source and a node destination.

And a way to list the nodes with no outgoing edges:

It assumes that the adjacency lists represent the edges twice: once going out, and once going in, typical of an undirected graph.

```
def edges(g):
    """return a list of tuples representing an edge
    """
    edges = []
    for source in g:
        for destination in g[source]:
            edges.append((source, destination))
    return edges


def isolated_nodes(g):
    """returns a list of the nodes with no outgoing edges
    """
    disconnected_nodes = []
    for node in g:
        if len(g[node]) == 0:
            disconnected_nodes.append(node)
    return disconnected_nodes


graph = { "v1" : ["v3"],
          "v2" : ["v3", "v5"],
          "v3" : ["v1", "v2", "v4", "v5"],
          "v4" : ["v3"],
          "v5" : ["v3", "v2"],
          "v6" : []
        }


print(edges(graph))
print(isolated_nodes(graph))
```

#### output:

```
[('v1', 'v3'), ('v2', 'v3'), ('v2', 'v5'), ('v3', 'v1'), ('v3', 'v2'), ('v3', 'v4'), ('v3', 'v5'), ('v4', 'v3'), ('v5', 'v3'), ('v5', 'v2')]
['v6']
```

Comment: Very good answer. I will go for Damian solution since he uses very little code.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph can contain directed edges, then just checking the adjacency lists for any given nodes is not enough. Instead, you could get `set`s for all the nodes that are a source or a target for some edge and collect those that are neither.

```
>>> targets = {n for lst in graph.values() for n in lst}
>>> sources = {n for n in graph if graph[n] != []}
>>> isolated = {n for n in graph if n not in sources and n not in targets}
>>> isolated
{'v6'}
```

Or using `set` methods:

```
>>> isolated = set(graph).difference(sources).difference(targets)
```